# Piglatin output won't work correctly still

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char firstLetter;
int pigLatin();
string word;
int wordFinder();
int firstVowel;
int x;
char vowel = ('a' && 'e' && 'i' && 'o' && 'u' && 'y' && 'A' && 'E' && 'I' && 'O' && 'U' && 'Y');
string engSentence;
char* letter = &engSentence[0];
bool vowelChecker (char c) // will check to see if there is a vowel
{
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'y' || c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' || c == 'Y')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int pigLatin()
{
    int lastLetter = word.length();
    firstLetter = word[0];


    if (vowelChecker(firstLetter)) //if the first letter of a word is a vowel...
    {
        cout << word << "way "; // print the word then way
    }
    else //if the first letter is not a vowel...
    {
        for (x = 1; x < lastLetter; x++) //in the loop of starting at the second letter and going to the last letter...
        {
            if (vowelChecker(x)) // check each letter to see if there is a vowel...
            {
                int firstVowel = x; //says that the first vowel is at point x
                break;
            }

        }
        string firstPortion = word.substr(0, firstVowel);
        string secondPortion = word.substr(firstVowel, lastLetter);
        cout << secondPortion << firstPortion << "ay";
        //above is stating that it will first print the part of the word from the first vowel to the last letter,
        //then it will print from the first letter to the first vowel and add 'ay' to the end

    }
    return 0;
}
int wordFinder() //will find words within a string
{
    char* letter = &engSentence[0];
    while ( *letter != '\0') //while the string isn't done...
    {
        if ( *letter == ' ' || *letter == '.' || *letter == ',' || *letter == '-' || *letter == '!' || *letter == '?') //if there is a space, comma or period...
        {
            pigLatin(); //run piglatin func
            cout << " "; // add a space before the next word
            word = "";  //sets the word back to empty

        }
        else
        {
            word += *letter; //adds letters to the word if no space comma or period is found.
        }
        letter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a sentence for me to translate: " << endl;
    cout << "**REMEMBER TO END SENTENCES WITH A PERIOD OR QUESTION MARK OR EXPLANATION MARK!**" << endl;

    getline(cin, engSentence); //will get the whole line entered
    wordFinder(); //runs wordfinder function
}
```

So far, it will only work for if the vowel is the first letter. ( if (vowelChecker(firstLetter)) { cout << word << "way ";} ) this portion of the text... The other part seems to not being ran through in the Piglatin Function. Also I'm Getting a warning that says that firstVowel isn't being used, which would explain why my program isn't running correctly. Not sure why though...

Comment: @DBug hit the money on your problem, `vowelChecker(x)` is passing in the index `x` which are numbers so they will never be vowels

Comment: i would also suggest initializing `firstVowel` to your last letter index when you initialize your firstLetter to ensure that `firstVowel` doesnt cause an error, ie if you put in a word/name that doesnt have a vowel (not really likely at all but you never know)

Comment: `char vowel = ('a' && 'e' && 'i' && 'o' && 'u' && 'y' && 'A' && 'E' && 'I' && 'O' && 'U' && 'Y');`  What did you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (vowelChecker(x)) // check each letter to see if there is a vowel...
```

this is passing the loop variable x, not the character at that position.  What you want is:

```
if (vowelChecker(word[x])) // check each letter to see if there is a vowel...
```